# Multiple Overrides in Ext JS

Tags: extjs

How are multiple overrides handled in Ext JS? Are they chained, or does the last one defined win? I need to decide whether to define an override or override a class directly when there are potentially multiple overrides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last one wins, but overridden functions are chained when calling `callParent`, as demonstrated in this [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2icq):

```
Ext.define('A', {
    a: function() {
        console.log('a');
    },
    A: 'A'
});
Ext.define('B', {
    override: 'A',
    a: function() {
        console.log('b');
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    A: 'B'
});

Ext.define('C', {
    override: 'A',
    a: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        console.log('c')
    },
    A: 'C'
});

var a = Ext.create('A')
a.a();
console.log(a.A);
```

Result in console:

> b
>   a
>   c
>   C